# L-systems and Sierpinski Triangle

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, fractals

I was just shocked when I saw these consecutive outcomes of an [L-system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) *converging* to the Sierpinski triangle (shown in [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Serpinski_Lsystem.svg/486px-Serpinski_Lsystem.svg.png) picture).

I'm interested to know how can one arrange the rules of an L-system so that it will converge to a desired subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ - in particular, to the Sierpinski triangle.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what would constitute an answer? You wont be able to get every subset of R^2

Comment: I didn't have such a broad and general question in my mind! It's good enough for me to know how has somebody made the rules of the L-system below  such that it converges to the Sierpinski triangle.  How has he/she thought about the problem. variables : A B
constants : + −
start  : A
rules  : (A → B−A−B), (B → A+B+A)
angle  : 60°

Comment: Nice to meet you, too.